# Getting back elements that are part of a has_many of a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following:

```
Menu 
  -items
    -notes
```

with a menu has_many items and an item has_many notes. I want all the notes for a menu.

I was thinking something like the following:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def notes
    items.where('notes.count > 0').notes #?
  end
```

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
  def notes
    Note.where('item_id in (?)', items.map(&:id)
  end
```

but that seems a bit ugly.

How would I just get back notes that are associated with items for that menu?

Comment: Doesn't this get you what you need? `items.map(&:notes)`

Comment: thx, but I think that will return back a bunch of empty arrays if there is non a note

Comment: items.map(&:items).reject(&:empty?).flatten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via associations:

```
class Menu
  has_many :items
  has_many :notes, through: :notes
end
```

It returns an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`, so you just get a chainable scope.